# Cannot create new Grails project in STS

Tags: grails

I am getting this error while creating a new Grails Project in STS 2.9.1

Command terminated with an error code (see details for output)
------System.out:-----------
 | Loading Grails 2.0.1
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Compiling 38 source files.
| Error Compilation error: startup failed:
Invalid commandline usage for javac.
javac: invalid flag: -Xlint:-options
Usage: javac  
use -help for a list of possible options
1 error
------System.err:-----------

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to a valid Oracle JDK-path of at least 1.6.0_14 and there is no `JAVA_OPTS` defined.

Comment: No. JAVA_OPTS are not defined. I am using JDK 1.7. Switched to 1.6 but same issue. This is happening when I am creating a new grails project and the command that is shown as executed is compile --non-interactive

Comment: Also this is happening while 'Updating Project Dependencies'

Comment: Yes. From command line I can execute the create-app successfully but when i execute create-domain-controller, this error occurs.

Comment: `create-domain-controller` is not existing. `create-domain-class` and `create-controller` is existing.

Comment: Sorry. I meant create-domain-class